# changing the name field of $_FILES when a file is uploaded using FormData blob

Tags: php, ajax, post, file-upload, plupload

so I'm using plupload which sends FILES using blobs appended ot FormData:

An exceprt from plupload.dev.js

```
formData = new o.FormData();

                // Add multipart params
                plupload.each(plupload.extend(args, up.settings.multipart_params), function(value, name) {
                    formData.append(name, value);
                });

                // Add file and send it
                formData.append(up.settings.file_data_name, chunkBlob);

                xhr.send(formData, {
                    runtime_order: up.settings.runtimes,
                    required_caps: up.settings.required_features,
                    preferred_caps: preferred_caps,
                    swf_url: up.settings.flash_swf_url,
                    xap_url: up.settings.silverlight_xap_url
                });
```

in which chunkBlob is the file Blob of the chunk to be sent...

now this parses into my server as the following:

```
 [$_FILES] => Array
        (
            [file] => Array
                (
                    [name] => blob
                    [type] => application/octet-stream
                    [tmp_name] => /tmp/php0BuCPN
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 102400000
                )

        )
```

and as you can see, it sets the name as 'blob'.....is there a way for me to configure the name used by formData when it's sending the blob using this method?

## Background problem

My server has upload_max_filesize  setup as 1024M ..... I'm using plupload to chunk my files in attempt to make it possible to upload files greater than 1024M .... each chunk is only 100M big.....however, an issue I'm facing is if the total filesize exceeds 1024M sometimes $_FILES and $_POST would end up being empty even if the individual blob size is just 100M...

My guess is that PHP uses the name field of $_FILES['file'] and finds out that these individual chunks are for the same file and would apply upload_max_filesize accordingly (even though each chunk is less than the upload_max_filesize limit)....so here I'm trying to change the name field if $_FILES['file'] so that PHP will treat each chunk as a separate file instead of the same file and hence have all the chunks upload successfully......<--let me know if there's something wrong with my reasoning here....